# Comparing two jquery ui autocomplete combobox values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-autocomplete

How to compare two jquery ui autocomplete combobox values, not input values that are generated by jquery but `<select><option value="foo"></option></select>` values? How to get this values and compare them, everytime they are changed, either one of them?

[image]

Comment: Can't you just get the underlying `<select>` value ? Someyhing like `$('select').val()` ?

Comment: @DidierGhys, yes i can, but how to compare these tow selected values, when fn select: is being used for both of them?

Comment: Differenciate them with an ID: `<select id="Combobox1">` and `<select id="Combobox2">`. Then you can compare the two values: `$('#Combobox1').val() !== $('#Combobox2').val()`

Comment: @DidierGhys, yes i am aware of selecting and comparing methods, but my problem is that this is now an input box, once jquery ui has been applied, and it does not recognise $('#Combobox1').change(function ()... enymore.. now it is input field, and it has its own methods inside called 'select' and 'change', so my problem is how to compare these two hidden values, without DOM knowing witch of them is being selected, and second thin is that both combo1, and combo2 use the same ui-method for generation, it would be stupid to create one method for every combobox, on my page over 10...

Comment: I think I get it now. Posted an answer for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not reallt understand your question correctly the first time.

I suppose you took the combobox code from the [jQuery UI Autocomplete demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) ?

If you look at the code, it triggers an event "selected" when a selection happens:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.option.selected = true;
    // triggers the "selected" event
    self._trigger("selected", event, {
        item: ui.item.option
    });
},
```

As the combobox example uses the jQuery UI Widget Factory, you can easily bind an event handler for this event from the options when initializing the plugin instance:

```
$( "#combobox" ).combobox({ 
    selected: function(e, ui) {
        // in here "ui.item" is the <option> selected
        // so you can use "ui.item.value"
    }
});
```

This will act as sort-of "change handler". In it, you have access to the **value** through `ui.item.value`.


**Working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/yNaG5/).**

Answer (score 0):

Try storing each value in an element, using jquerys data method: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Usage example:

```
$('#combobox10').data('key', 'value');
```

edit:

Set the value:

```
$('#combobox10').data('key', 'foo');
```

Get the value:

```
var combobox10value = $('#combobox10').data('key');
alert(combobox10value); // will alert 'foo'
```

Comment: can you provide example of this?

Comment: ok, but how to get the <option value="foo"> value so it can be set to .data('key','value')?